# Generating an HTML entity with an XSL transform

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, html-entities

I'm using XSLT (with the Saxon XSLT processor) to generate a markdown file. My problem is to insert HTML in the markdown file to compose a superscripted registration mark.

I put this style sheet definition near the front of the XML input:

```
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
  <!ENTITY xreg    "<sup>&reg;</sup>" >
]>
```

To compose a registration mark I write this:

```
The Bogus&xreg; Intelligence Engine is...
```

I expect the XSLT processor to encounter the entity '&xreg;' and transform it into '<sup>&reg;</sup>' in the output. Instead I get this error:

```
Error on line 51 column 13 of part_config.xml:
  SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The entity "reg" was referenced, but not declared.
```

(Line 51 column 13 is the space following '&xreg;'.)

As I understood the word "referenced," the entity "xreg" was referenced, and is declared. If "referenced" indicates the result of the transformation rather than the entity in the source, there's no way I could declare the "referenced" entity that's meaningfully different from what I did.

It occurred to me that XSLT may be trying to resolve the entities *recursively*. In that case it seems to me that I'm doomed: If I don't define the "reg" entity in the XML style sheet I'll get the error I just got; if I define it as itself I'll get a recursive definition error; and if I define it as anything else I'll get incorrect output.

What does XSLT want me to do?

Comment: What is your output method? And is there a reason why you can't have `<sup>®</sup>` as the output?

Answer (score 0):

> I expect the XSLT processor to encounter the entity '&xreg;' and transform it into '<sup>&reg;</sup>' in the output.

I'll do you one better: you can write `&reg;` and have the XSLT processor transform it into `<sup>&reg;</sup>` in the output. Simply place this DTD at the top of your stylesheet:

```
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
<!ENTITY reg    "&lt;sup>&amp;reg;&lt;/sup>" >
]>
```

This is assuming your `xsl:output method` is "text".

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdHj

---

Of course, you could do simply:

```
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
<!ENTITY reg    "&lt;sup>®&lt;/sup>" >
]>
```

to have the XSLT processor transform your entry of:

```
<xsl:text>The Bogus&reg; Intelligence Engine is...</xsl:text>
```

into:

```
The Bogus<sup>®</sup> Intelligence Engine is...
```

Comment: "&lt;sup>&amp;reg;&lt;/sup>" works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Using '®' was the fallback position, but it's undesirable because many HTML tools (including some we use) don't allow extended ASCII characters. I found that the Saxon XSL processor does, but I don't want to create output that may make a necessary tool choke at an inconvenient time in the future.

Comment: If a tool does not allow `®`, then what character does it output when it encounters `&reg;`? I think that `&reg;`, `&#172;` or `®` are different representations of the same character. It makes no sense to allow one but not the other.

Comment: Michael: I didn't say exactly literally what I meant. I'm speaking of tools that donot tolerate characters outside the 96-character ASCII character set in *input*. Of course they translate entities to the appropriate extended characters if translation is part of their function.

Answer (score -1):

Entity references are understood and processed by the XML parser; they are expanded by the XML parser before the XSLT processor gets a look in. The source document and stylesheet are completely unrelated as far as the XML parser is concerned, so it is not possible for an entity reference in the stylesheet to resolve to an entity declaration in the source document.

Furthermore, entity references are not recognized in the XDM data model which defines what an XSLT stylesheet actually manipulates; therefore the XSLT processor cannot create entity references in its result tree.

You're presumably using the text output method to generate markdown. With the text output method, special characters like "&" are not subjected to XML-escaping, so if your stylesheet does

```
<xsl:text>&amp;reg;</xsl:text>
```

then it will be serialized as `&reg;`.

You could also do this within a DOCTYPE declaration in the stylesheet. If the stylesheet includes:

```
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
  <!ENTITY xreg    "<sup>&amp;reg;</sup>" >
]>
```

Then you can do

```
<xsl:text>&xreg;</xsl:text>
```

and this will create a text node containing the five characters `& r e g ;`, which the method="text" serializer will output as-is, with no escaping of the ampersand.

Comment: If you declare  `<!ENTITY xreg    "<sup>&amp;reg;</sup>" >` and then do `<xsl:text>&xreg;</xsl:text>`, you will get an error: `xsl:text must not contain child elements`.